# Windows Server network card transferring files at 100 Mb/s on the LAN

Tags: networking, file-transfer, windows-server

I was transferring a file over my local network, from a Windows Server to an Hyper-V Server.

The Windows Server has a Gigabit Ethernet network card, and the Hyper-V Server a Gigabit too.

When transferring the file (I used the Windows Explorer window to connect to the Hyper-V Server, and another Explorer window to drag and drop the file from the Windows Server to the Hyper-V Server), I noticed that the transfer speed was limited to 100 Mb/s.

My whole network use cat. 6A cables, and the switch between those servers is a Gigabit one.

All drivers are up to date, firmwares too.

Anything to do here? Is it maybe normal?

**EDIT:** I noticed that the network card of the Windows server is running at it's maximum capacity.

**EDIT 2:** tried a new transfer, Windows server's network card is at ~980 Mb of transfer, but the Hyper-V one is running at 260-280 Mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other network equipment, such as router, hub or switch in between 2 computers should also support Gigabit Ethernet or higher speeds, otherwise it is limiting network speed down to the highest it supports.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The whole network is running at Gigabit.

Comment: Can you confirm, that both PC network cards display gigabit connection speed in connection status?

Comment: The Windows Server's one is displaying 1 Gbits/s, and the Hyper-V Server one is also a 1 Gbit/s one (I thought it was a 10 Gb one).

Comment: Btw no router is intervening here, since my two servers are connected to the same switch.

Comment: Can the transfer be limited by storage device installed in the computers? What is the throughput capacities for reading and writing at both computers?

Comment: Ok, it seems that my drives were slow... thanks for your concern!